# How to make Socket.io work with a CapacitorJS native app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, socket.io, capacitor

How do you make **Socket.io** work with a **CapacitorJS native app** for iOS or Android (even on emulators)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pass** your **backend server URL** to the socket.io client **on initialisation**, as follows:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const connect = () => {
  const socket = io("https://www.example.com/", { options });
  return socket;
};
```

as per the official documentation: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#from-a-different-domain